# Excel countif date in cell is greater than or equal to date in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, countif

This has been killing me for a while now. I just need to count a cell if the date in that cell is greater than or equal to a date in another cell (minus x days).

For example:

> A1 2/20/2014
>
> B1 1/20/2014
>
> =COUNTIF(B1, ">=A1-30")

-30 would be minus 30 days. This obviously does not work. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
=COUNTIF(B1, ">=" & A1-30)
```

Comment: You are a gentleman (gentlewoman?) and a scholar. THANK YOU. I can't believe I didn't try it like this before...