# Counting overdue completion dates

Tags: excel, formula, external

I'm trying to write a formula to count how many employees are overdue for a task.  The catch is that the completion dates and due dates are kept in multiple separate workbooks that I would prefer not to be opened in order to use the formula (no countif).  Because of this, I think sumproduct is my best option.  The formula I have right now is:

```
=sumproduct('location of workbook'!W37:W189,"">'location of workbook'!$S$9)
```

where `W37:W189` references the completion dates and `$S$9` references the due date.  When I run the formula, I get a `#VALUE!` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUMPRODUCT` function is for multiplying array values with their corresponding entries in another array and then summing those to obtain a total value. It only works with numbers, not dates. Since the 2nd parameter you pass is a string, rather than the expected array range, you get the `#VALUE!` error.

See [Excel countif date in cell is greater than or equal to date in another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917381/excel-countif-date-in-cell-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-date-in-another-cell#21917417) -- you need to enclose the condition operator in double quotes `">"` and use ampersand `&` to append the date value to compare with.

I believe `COUNTIF` is the function you are after; this counts all the cells in the 1st parameter range that meet the condition in the 2nd parameter, e.g.

```
=COUNTIF('[workbook]SheetName'!W37:W189, ">" & '[workbook]SheetName'!$S$9)
```

**Note**: As OP commented, this only seems to work if the workbook mentioned in the first parameter is also open. Not sure why. The other workbook may be closed. If the first workbook is closed, you need the following workaround:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[workbook]SheetName'!W37:W189>'[workbook]SheetName'!$S$9))
```

Sorry, I do not know why this workaround works. I found it mentioned in [this thread on MrExcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/263240-countif-closed-workbook.html)

Comment: replaced sumproduct with countif but I'm still getting the #VALUE! message...I also added & in front of the location and the quotations marks for the operator.

Comment: It looks like the issue may have to do with the workbook being closed.  Since I will be dealing with multiple workbooks and do not want to have to open them all, countif may not be the best option.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first param workbook needs to be open. The second param does not. Hmm!